# How to Find queryGuid in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

I am trying to do [this](https://github.com/idanpl/tfs-query-reporter) example.

In here the added `queryGuid` to Appconfig file. Can anyone please help me to find that `queryGuid` in TFS.

This is the tag in Appconfig:

```
 <add key="queryGuid" value="12345678-d96b-4f03-9ceb-1b49de27ef41"/>
```

Comment: Just open a query in your tfs and copy the guid from the browser-url. should be something like "{TFSUrl}/{ProjectName}/_queries/query/12345678-d96b-4f03-9ceb-1b49de27ef41/"

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a query you can see the Query GUID on the url:

```
https://tfs-server:8080/tfs/Collection/Project/_queries/query/{Query GUID}
```

[image]

If you want to get daily mails for TFS queries you can install also [Scheduled Work Item Query](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Quadrotech.ADOScheduledWorkItemQuery&ssr=false#overview) extnsion, it's a new extension that sends an E-Mail on a schedule for Work Item Queries.

[image]